# Class composition with public member objects

Tags: c++, oop

I am trying to figure out the best way to design my program features.

A major component of the program is a Camera class.  This Camera object represents the program user interface to a real camera, which interfaces to a computer through a frame grabber card.  The camera class can link to a frame grabber, start and stop acquisition, and also mutate/access *many* different camera properties.  When I say many, I'm talking about over 250 unique commands.  Each unique command is issued to the camera by sending a serial string through the framegrabber to the physical camera.  Each command can be thought of as one of three types.  An action, a query, and a value.

An action command is something that doesn't require an equals sign, for example "reset", "open", "close"

A query is something that you can get, but not set, that is usually associated with a value. For example "temperature=?", "sernum=?", "maxframerate=?" commands would cause the camera to send back information.  These values cannot be mutated so "temperature=20" would result in an error.

A value is something you can get and set that is usually associated with a value.  For example "framerate=30" and "framerate=?" are two unique commands, but I consider the base string "framerate" to be a value command type because it can be both mutated and accessed.

The 250 unique commands can be reduced to ~100 CameraActions, CameraQuerys, and CameraValues. Instead of having 250 methods in my Camera class, I had an idea to compose command objects instead of individual setters, getters, and actions.  The command string can be provided in the constructor, or reset with a setter. Then I could compose a CameraCommands object that holds all of the available commands, and provide that as a public member to my Camera.

```
//CameraAction.h =============================================
class CameraAction {
public:
  CameraAction(std::string commandString, SerialInterface* serialInterface);
  void operator()() { _serialInterface->sendString(_commandString); }

private:
  SerialInterface* _serialInterface;
  std::string      _commandString;

}; 


//CameraValue.h =====================================================
class CameraValue {

public:

  CameraValue(std::string commandString, double min, double max, SerialInterface* serialInterface);

  void set(double value)
  {
    if(value > _maxValue) { throw std::runtime_error("value too high"); }
    if(value < _minValue) { throw std::runtime_error("value too low"); }
    std::string valueString = std::to_string(value);
    _serialInterface->sendString(_commandString + "=" + valueString);
  }

  double get()
  {
    std::string valueString = _serialInterface->sendString(_commandString + "=?");
    return atof(valueString.c_str());
  }

private:

  SerialInterface* _serialInterface;
  std::string      _commandString;
  double           _minValue;
  double           _maxValue;

};  


//CameraCommands.h ===================================================
class CameraCommands {

public:
  CameraCommands();
  CameraAction reset;
  CameraQuery  temperature;
  CameraValue  framerate;
  CameraValue  sensitivity;
  //... >100 more of these guys

};


//Camera.h ===========================================================
class Camera {
public:
  Camera();
  CameraCommands cmd;
  void startAcquisition();
  void stopAcquisition();
  void setDataBuffer(void* buffer);
  void setOtherThing(int thing);
};
```

so that the user could do something like:

```
Camera myCamera;
myCamera.cmd.reset();
myCamera.cmd.framerate.set(30);
myCamera.cmd.sensitivity.set(95);
double temperature = myCamera.cmd.temperature.get();
myCamera.startAcquisition();
```

etc...

The main problem here is that I'm exposing public member variables, which is supposed to be a massive no-no.  Is my current object design logical, or should I simply implement 250 setters and getters and 100 more setters and getters to mutate the minimum and maximum settable values.

This seems kludgey to me because there are also many setters/getters associated with the Camera object that are unrelated to the user commands.  It's nice for the user interface to provide the scope of the method (cmd) for the user to know whether something is being mutated physically in the camera, or just being mutated in the programmatic object (other methods).  Is there any better way to design my program?

Comment: This seems to be mostly a matter of interface design. You'll have to decide how you want to write code that interacts with your `Camera` class, then figure out a way to make your interface as close to that as possible. To me, the `camera.cmd.foo` syntax seems to have the redundant `cmd` part. I'd prefer to be able to write `Temperature t = camera.temperature();` or `camera.setFrameRate(6);` or even `camera.frameRate = 6;` Exposing member variables isn't necessarily problematic as long as they are designed to safely accessed by a user who doesn't (need to) know the interaction between them.

Comment: Your first couple of sentences really hit home.  I'm trying to make the internal workings of the program clean and easily extensible, but I'm not really thinking at all about the best way for a user to interact with the API.   So far, a lot of suggestions seem to like camera.frameRate = 5;  It's a great concept, but probably confusing for other people looking at the code.  I need to think more deeply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've basically described an interesting hierarchy:

`Command` -> `Query` -> `Value`.

- A `Command` holds the string that is the text of the command;
  It can also offer a `protected` `Send()` method for its children to call.
- A `Query` also holds a (`protected`) `int` variable (or whatever) that you can `get()` and/or `operator int()` immediately, or `query()` from the camera;
- A `Value` adds the `set()` and/or `operator =(int)` command to `Query`.

The constructor (in particular) of `Value` can have `min` and `max` as you describe.

The `Camera` object can then have a number of `public` members:

```
class Camera {

private: // Classes that no-one else can have!

    class Command; friend Command;
#include "Camera.Command.inc"

    class Query; friend Query;
#include "Camera.Query.inc"

    class Value; friend Value;
#include "Camera.Value.inc"

public: // Variables using above classes

    Command reset;
    Command open;  // Maybe make this one private, for friends?
    Command close; // Ditto?

    Query temperature;
    Query sernum;
    Query maxFrameRate;

    Value frameRate;

private: // Variables

    SerialPort port; // Allow Command and co. access to this

}; // Camera
```

By organising it like this, then:

- The user of the variables can't make impossible requests - there is no method to do so;
- The `query()` and `set()` methods hide the mechanism to interface with the physical camera.

You'll note I've added `#include "Camera.XXX.inc"` in the middle of the `Camera` class. Note:

1. It doesn't clutter the Camera class with the definitions of those sub-Classes - but the C++ compiler needs them before you can use them, so you need to have them there. And if you want to know what they do, just open the file!
2. I gave them the `.inc` extension since they're "included" in the `.h` file: they don't stand alone as their own header file.

Comment: I really like this concept and inheritance.  I'm not sure if having includes inside of your class is common practice, but I've never thought about it before and it would be very useful to me in other scenarios where nested classes are an eye-sore.  What is the purpose of making Camera friends with Command, Query, and Value?

Comment: @Sam So that they can access `SerialPort` (or whatever you call it). You need to pass `Camera` into each `Command`, so why not store the SerialPort there for their use? Maybe only `Command` needs to be `friend`s - maybe none.

Comment: @Sam Note also my file naming scheme: it's obvious which main header the `inc` is for. But also note that if the parent class only needs refs or pointers to the child classes, you can leave the `class XXX;` inside the class, but actually put the `#include` elsewhere.

Comment: So you're saying Command will have a private member that is a Camera* pointer to this, and through that pointer (that is sent in the constructor) I will be able to access the private SerialPort?  Or is access to the Camera::port more simple / direct than that?

Comment: I'd use a ref (`&`) instead of a pointer (`*`). Note though if that's the only reason you need a back-reference, you might think about making `serialPort` `private static` inside `Camera` - that way `Command` won't need a back-ref, it can use `Camera::serialPort` instead of `camera.serialPort`. That means only one Camera connected at a time, so I think it's best to put in the back-ref from the beginning.

Comment: The more I think about it, the more I think that the `int` in `Query` should be `private`. `Value` shouldn't touch it: it should only `Send()` the requested new value, then the response could update `Query`'s `int`

Comment: Unfortunately, in this case I need to connect up to four cameras at a single time.  I was also thinking about the static serial port for a long time until I determined it just wouldn't work in this instance.  One more question related to design (because I'm new-ish).  Why would you recommend storing a reference to the camera instead of a pointer.  Would anything be different aside from the syntax of accessing the camera data?  Also, what would happen if the Command accessed itself through its Camera reference?  I feel like there's got to be some kind of practical coding violation

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114768/discussion-between-sam-wilton-and-john-burger).

Comment: @Sam A pointer has only one drawback compared to a reference: it could be 0, so you need to check for that. A reference has only one drawback compared to a pointer: it can't be reassigned. But `Camera` holds individual `Command`s, `Query`s and `Value`s, whose existence is inside `Camera`, and don't belong to any other `Camera`. So a reference is perfect: it doesn't need to be reassigned, and its referent cant just disappear - not before the `Command` does anyway!

Answer (score 0):

You can use one or more structs to group "settings", and then expose a method to set them:

```
typedef struct settings{
  int setting1;
  int setting2;
}MySettings;

class Myclass{
 private :
   int setting1;
   int setting2;

 public Myclass(MySettigs *settings)
{
  if(null != settings){
     setting1=settings->setting1;
     setting2=settings->setting2;
  }
}

public void ChangeSettings (MySettings *setting){
  if(null != settings)
  {
     setting1=settings->setting1;
     setting2=settings->setting2;
  }
}

public void TakeSettings (MySettigs *settings){
  [copy local variables into the passed struct]
}
```

I strongly advise to be careful when changing settings while the object is "operational".You can fall in an undefined state where settings are being changed while another thread is using them.

Answer (score 0):

In your mentioned design I don't think exposing public members through composition is a big no-no.

When exposing public members, the big no-no is *unsafe* access to your class internals.

An example would be allowing public access to `CameraValue::_maxValue`. A user could change that value to anything, causing all sorts of undefined behaviour.

Were it up to me to design this I wouldn't have a `CameraCommands` member, as from the looks of it it doesn't add anything other then a level of indirection.

I would either add all the `CameraAction` and `CameraValue` members as part of the camera class, or inherit them.

Something like this:

**Merging `CameraCommands` into `Camera`:**

```
class Camera 
{
public:
  Camera();

  CameraAction reset;
  CameraQuery  temperature;
  CameraValue  framerate;
  CameraValue  sensitivity;
  //... >100 more of these guys

  void startAcquisition();
  void stopAcquisition();
  void setDataBuffer(void* buffer);
  void setOtherThing(int thing);
};
```

**Inheriting `CameraCommands` into `Camera`:**

```
class Camera : public CameraCommands
{
public:
  Camera();

  void startAcquisition();
  void stopAcquisition();
  void setDataBuffer(void* buffer);
  void setOtherThing(int thing);
};
```

You can even provide some operators for `CameraValue` etc so that you can set a value through assignment (`operator=`), and get a value through either implicit conversion (`operator T`) or dereferencing (`operator*`):

```
template<typename T>
class CameraValue
{
public
    CameraValue(SerialInterface*, std::string cmd);

    CameraValue& operator=(const T& val)
    {
        _val = val;
        std::string val_str = std::to_string(_val);
       _ser_ifc->sendString(_cmd + "=" + val_str);            
    }

    const T& get() const
    {
        return _val;
    }

    // implicit access to _val
    operator const T&() const
    {
        return _val;
    }

    // dereference operator to access _val
    const T& operator*() const
    {
        return _val;
    }
private:
    T _val;
    SerialInterface* _ser_ifc;
    std::string      _cmd;
};
```

Then use `CameraValue` in your class as follows:

```
using CameraFramerate = CameraValue<int>;

CameraFramerate framerate;
```

The above techniques offer (IMO) a more composable use of `Camera`, such as the following:

```
Camera camera;

// setting values
camera.framerate = 30;
camera.sensitivity = 95;

// getting values
int framerate =  camera.framerate; // uses operator T&()
int framerate = *camera.framerate; // uses operator*()
```

The key point here is that `Camera::framerate` etc don't allow any access that could change your camera class' internal state in an undefined and/or unsafe manner.